# Best tool for multivariate nonlinear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, prediction, nonlinear-regression

I have a data set which has 7 continuous variables, `r0 ... r6` and I need to predict 2 continuous variables, `x` and `y`. These variables are quite correlated but the pattern is nonlinear.

To explain the relationship between each variable, the problem is a little bit as follows: `r0` to `r6` are the radii of different circles, whose centre, `(x0, y0) ... (x6, y6)`, we do not know. We want to predict `(x,y)` where the circles intersect each other.

With a training data set with rows that looks like this:

`[32,15,12,11,19,24,12],[35.124,14.224]`

I am hoping to find a tool which gives me the coordinates for unseen values of `r0` to `r6`.

In reality `r0` to `r6` are actually sensor readings, so they won't be actual radii, and they will be noisy, but the example hopefully explains the nonlinear relationship between them.

I am very new to regression and machine learning in general, so I am hoping to be pointed to the right toolset to use in this case. What is the best tool to look at? Do I need to do any pre-processing to make the input more compatible with the existent tools?

Comment: Can you explain the underlying problem in more detail? It sounds ill-posed. If you just know radiuses, then the intersection point should be undefined - consider that a rigid rotation of the plane would leave the relative position of the intersection point with respect to the circles centers unchanged, but it would change the intersection point's coordinates. Also, the existence of an intersection is not guaranteed even for just three circles, and you have six! Are you sure on physical grounds that there is always an intersection? Is this an inverse problem, i.e., do you have ctd...

Comment: ...ctd arrival times of the same wave, originating from an unknown point, at six different sensor locations? In this case you know that there's an intersection. This is extensively studied for seismic waves - I would have a look at the relevant literature. Also, inverse problems are always annoying - the solution may not exist, be numerically ill-conditioned and be overly sensitive to data (large variance). Whatever method you choose to use,  I think you should add regularization, to make sure you that you find a solution, and to reduce the variance of your estimate of the intersection point.

Comment: *Palpatable*?..

Comment: @DeltaIV The formulation of the radii was just my (somewhat naive way) to try to explain the known relationship between the input variables on the output. In reality it is not even a radius or anything like that (signal has attenuation due to obstacles etc.) so don't take it as a precise relationship. In the real problem yes the intersection exists, because the input was generated from an `(x,y)` that did all the 7 readings. The problem is somewhat similar to CTD (just opposite, the sensor is at `(x,y)` and measuring signals from beacons whose location is not known).

Comment: @RichardHardy I meant 'palatable' ... but reworded :)

Comment: @jbx ok, so it's the same scenario as seismic inversion: there you have reflections, attenuation, refraction at the interface between different geological strata, etc.. And it's an inverse problem  (from $N$ measurements of the intensity of a field, locate the sources and their intensity), so it's ill-posed. Have a look at [seismic inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_inversion). Bayesian methods naturally include regularization thanks to the prior, so I would look into those. Another source you could consider is the field of spatio-temporal statistics.